# C# editing DataTable changes not saved

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm have a problem whereby I have created a DataTable object in one class and returned it to the main program. I call a method(1) that retrieves some information from the data table and deletes the same rows afterwards. I then run another method(2) which retrieves data from a column but I can see that the rows that I deleted in the other method(1) have not taken affect. I have counted the number of rows in method(1) and the number of rows do decrease which indicates that they have been deleted.

Could this be something to do with referencing objects?

Apologies in advance for any mistakes I've made in asking this question. It#s my first question to the Stack and I'm still pretty new to coding.

Thanks in advance!

Main Program:

```
filepath = @"E:\1802370 11.05.18 qCML 6x10E6 ERM_analysed.txt";

//Create a datatable from _analysed file and delete unwated columns
DataTable dataTable = csv.convertToDataTable(filepath);

//Assign slope and r2 values for both BCR and ABL
//Delete rows after
plate.getSlopeandR2(dataTable);
plate.getSampleList(dataTable);
```

DataTable method:

```
    //Converts text file into a datatable to be manipluated.
    public DataTable convertToDataTable(string filepath)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);

        string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split('\t');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header);
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = Regex.Split(sr.ReadLine(), "\t");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            {
                dr[i] = rows[i];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        sr.Close();
        return dt;
```

Method(1): Get values delete rows

```
    //Get slope and r2 values
    //Delete rows after info is retrieved
    public void getSlopeandR2(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        bool isABL = true;
        List<int> rowsToDelete = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows.Count);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            int rowIndex;

            if (row["Well"].ToString() == "Slope" && isABL == true)
            {
                rowIndex = dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                ablSlope = Convert.ToDouble(dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][1]);
                ablR2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataTable.Rows[rowIndex + 2][2]);
                isABL = false;
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 1);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 2);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 3);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 4);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 5);

            }
            else if (row["Well"].ToString() == "Slope" && isABL == false)
            {
                rowIndex = dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                biomedSlope = Convert.ToDouble(dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][1]);
                biomedR2 = Convert.ToDouble(dataTable.Rows[rowIndex + 2][2]);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 1);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 2);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 3);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 4);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 5);
                rowsToDelete.Add(rowIndex + 6);
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsToDelete.Count; i++)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Rows.Count);
    }
```

Method(2): Retrieval of data (deleted rows are still included)

```
        //Get unique list of sample ID's on plate
    public void getSampleList(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        string tempValue;

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (!Samples.Contains(row["Sample Name"].ToString()))
            {
                tempValue = Convert.ToString(row["Sample Name"]);
                Samples.Add(tempValue);
            }
        }

        foreach (string id in Samples)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The DAtaTable is declared local inside the method (DataTable dt = new DataTable();)  Move it outside the method so it can be recognized globally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried what you said but it's still behaving like it did.

Comment: Do try `plate.getSlopeandR2(ref dataTable);` !

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to delete DataRow from DataTable. Once you read file, call AcceptChanges() to commit DataTable internally.

```
//Created new table sample
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("dt1");
dt1.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("Name");

//Added dummy data
dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Abc");
dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Def");

//You must accept changes after reading file, so you can track changes
dt1.AcceptChanges();

//Below line will remove row permanently.
dt1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

//Below line will mark row as deleted, still row count will be same till AcceptChanges() called.
dt1.Rows[0].Delete();
dt1.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting rows from the table accept the changes

**dataTable.AcceptChanges()**

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsToDelete.Count; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
```